How to make local imports work after installing package with pip?
I have project structured like this:
$ tree . 
.
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── project
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── main.py
        └── module.py

$ cat pyproject.toml 
[project]
name = "project"
version = "0.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project.scripts]
launcher = "project.main:main"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

$ cat src/project/main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import module

def main():
    module.function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

For testing purpose module.function() just prints "Hello world!". main.py is executable so I can run it directly, but most of the time I use 'play' button in vscode. Problem starts when I install the project with pip install . and try to use entry point:
$ launcher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/project/.venv/bin/launcher", line 5, in <module>
    from project.main import main
  File "/some/path/project/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/project/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'

When I change import line to from project import module I can use launcher and I can run script directly but only if the package is installed. Otherwise there is an error:
$ src/project/main.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/project/src/project/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from project import module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

The question is how should I import module.py so I can run it with launcher and directly whenever installed or not.
Should I configure that in pyproject.toml so the generated launcher script would work with simple import module?
Or maybe in __init__.py because what is this file for if not to properly initialize the package?
I wanted to learn about packaging process and was looking in setuptools documentation for some hints, but haven't found anything related.
I tried also relative import from . import module but this works only when run with launcher and never directly:
$ src/project/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/project/src/project/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import module
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Finally I made it work in both cases like that:
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import module

But it seems to me like an ugly hack to mess around with sys.path and it entails other imports that may be unnecessary. I'm looking for nice and recommended way to solve the problem.


I don't have your code in module, so I mock one:

# module.py
def function():
    print("Hello world!")


Add a runner script named run.py in src folder

# run.py
from project.main import main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


fix the main.py to use absolute imports:

# main.py
from project import module

def main():
    module.function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Run runner script

python3 src/run.py
Hello world!


Non-Pythonic way to avoid mess around with sys.path
import os
import sys
if os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Pythonic way:

write a setup.py based on what you need.


pip install --editable `your_path`


Firstly, that doesn't answer my question. As I already wrote, when I use absolute import I cannot run the script until it is installed with pip. It is convenient to run it directly from vscode during development, before it is installed. Moreover, the program is more portable that way. You can just copy and run without installing. Secondly there is no need for another runner script. launcher is the runner script generated by pip, apart from that main.py is to be run directly.

@Feasuro OK, I see. I'll update my answer.
